# Android NDK location not found android studio on Mac?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I recently downloaded Android Studio 3.5.1. Have also downloaded all the SDK tools
    [image: enter code here]

Error I am getting

[image]

this is the android sdk folder content

[image]

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the path only. Apparently android studio downloaded ndk as
Library/Android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570/allfiles
I had to rename the ndk folder to ndk-bundle and moved the subfolder files to ndk folder.

Comment: AS 3.5 uses [NDK side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348606/192373) and does not need **ndk-bundle** anymore, if you remove the **ndk** line from **local.properties**. You can choose the NDK version for gradle build (e.g. `android.ndkVersion '19.2.5345600'`), or the latest will be picked.

Comment: "I had to rename the ndk folder to ndk-bundle and moved the subfolder files to ndk folder." Remove ndk.dir from your local.properties instead. How did that end up there in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.
`/your/path/Android/sdk/ndk/20.0.5594570`

But in case you are creating a native application using Android Studio, I think you should not locate for your `ndk` path manual.

Comment: This works, but isn't the most correct fix. Best is to delete the line entirely and set `android.ndkVersion` in the build.gradle.

Comment: @DanAlbert
"but isn't the most correct fix" please explain what it means and why?

Comment: See my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `ndk.dir` line from your build.gradle. That's the older method of specifying the NDK to use, and that path is wrong for the NDK you've installed.

AGP 3.5 allows you to install multiple NDKs simultaneously (if you check the "show package details" box you'll see that "NDK (Side by side)" expands) and select which one to use in your build.gradle with `android.ndkVersion`.

You can continue using `ndk.dir` for now, but it's deprecated and there isn't much reason to.

See https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk for more information.